# Rounding time untill in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with timestamp that I want to round off at 15 min. interval. I can round off using the below Query but it rounds off both 11:58 and 12:02 to 12:00 which is not what I want. I would like to round off timestamp at 15 min. interval which gives me time_untill ie for anything between 11:45 to 11:59 should be rounded off to 12 and anything between 12:00 to 12:14 should be rounded off to 12:15. Please let me know how can I achieve that? Thanks

```
SELECT transaction_id, 
 CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CONVERT(float, CONVERT(datetime,   entry_date_time)) * 96.0, 0, 1) /96.0)   as transaction_datetime
     FROM <table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datetimefromparts()`:

```
select dateadd(minute,
               15,
               datetimefromparts(year(entry_date_time), month(entry_date_time), day(entry_date_time),
                                 datepart(hour, entry_date_time),
                                 15 * (datepart(minute, entry_date_time) / 15), 0, 0
                                )
              ) as roundup15
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DATEADD/DATEDIFF method to truncate date/time values that's been available for a long time.

```
SELECT transaction_id,
        entry_date_time,
        DATEADD( MI, DATEDIFF( MI, '2010', entry_date_time)/15*15, '2010')    as transaction_datetime
--FROM Sample Data
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) transaction_id,
                DATEADD( SS, CHECKSUM(NEWID())%10000, CAST( GETDATE() AS smalldatetime)) AS entry_date_time
            FROM sys.columns)x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
DECLARE @time TIME(0) = GETDATE();

SELECT 
    DATEADD(MINUTE,
        (((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', @time) % 60) / 15) * 15),
        DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, '00:00:00', @time), '00:00:00')
        );
```